# HOG Feature Extraction using python

Tags: python

I have face some issue to my project. I have save 3 image that need to be extract the feature into a folder name test. After I run the code feature extracted image will save to another folder name Train to check whether HOG feature extraction function is work or not, but I have no idea why there is no image save to that folder. Anyone can help?

Attachment below is my code

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray

import cv2
from skimage.feature import hog
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import glob

IMG_HEIGHT = 28
IMG_WIDTH = 28

path = "C:/Users/TTT/Desktop/SVM Pic/test/*.*"
img_number = 0


def imresize(arr,size):       # def is define function; imresize is function name; arr and size is argument
    img=Image.fromarray(arr)  #img (self put name), function name
    img=img.resize(size)
    return asarray(img)

for file in glob.glob(path):
    a = cv2.imread(file)

    im_digit = imresize(a, (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))

# HOG feature extraction
def pixels_to_hog_20(img_array):
    hog_featuresData = []
    for img in img_array:
        fd = hog(im_digit, 
             orientations=10,
             pixels_per_cell=(5,5),    #size of number of cells 5*5
             cells_per_block=(1,1), visualize=True)
        hog_featuresData.append(fd)
    hog_features = np.array(hog_featuresData, 'float64')


    return np.float32(hog_features)

    cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/TTT/Desktop/SVM Pic/Train/HOG "+str(img_number)+".png", img, cmap="gray")

    img_number +=1
```

Comment: you return before you save. return after.

Comment: or your indentation is all wrong :)

Comment: also you have to actually call your methods, not just define them.

Comment: cv2.imwrite(...) I should put after return and call hog_features?